# Is there a better way to do this code? Perhaps using filter or reduce?

Tags: javascript

The code I have is correct, I'm just curious if there is a shorter way to do this?

I think a filter would be the best method but I'm not so sure how to use it.

```js
function tallEnoughToRide(group) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
    if (group[i].heightInInches >= 48) {
      result.push(group[i].name);
    }
  }
  return result; //should return a list of people taller than 48 inches
}

var groupA = [{
    name: "Mia",
    age: 10,
    heightInInches: 52
  },
  {
    name: "Jaya",
    age: 9,
    heightInInches: 45
  },
  {
    name: "Kiana",
    age: 10,
    heightInInches: 55
  },
  {
    name: "Alex",
    age: 11,
    heightInInches: 48
  }
];
console.log(tallEnoughToRide(groupA));
```

Comment: Does "shorter" mean easier for humans to use or easier for the computer?

Comment: `let result = groupA.filter(p => p.heightInInches >= 48).map(p => p.name)`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking how to improve working code. ask on [codereview.se]

Comment: @RonSkinner - Please review the [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) and [Expected Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) before commenting again. Your question is off-topic here, and fits on the Code Review site, as linked by Daniel. There's absolutely nothing wrong with such feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two things

1. [**.filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var groupA = [{
    name: "Mia",
    age: 10,
    heightInInches: 52
  },
  {
    name: "Jaya",
    age: 9,
    heightInInches: 45
  },
  {
    name: "Kiana",
    age: 10,
    heightInInches: 55
  },
  {
    name: "Alex",
    age: 11,
    heightInInches: 48
  }
];

console.log(groupA.filter(ele => ele.heightInInches >= 48))
```

You can see in the above snippet, the `filter` method is filtering out objects based on the condition.

2. [**.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
var groupA = [{
    name: "Mia",
    age: 10,
    heightInInches: 52
  },
  {
    name: "Jaya",
    age: 9,
    heightInInches: 45
  },
  {
    name: "Kiana",
    age: 10,
    heightInInches: 55
  },
  {
    name: "Alex",
    age: 11,
    heightInInches: 48
  }
];
console.log(groupA.map(obj => obj.name));
```

You can see in the above snippet, the `map` method is mapping out objects based on the key provided.

Now you can combine both `.filter()` and `.map()` together.

```js
function tallEnoughToRide(group) {

  return group.filter(ele => ele.heightInInches >= 48).map(obj => obj.name)
}

var groupA = [{
    name: "Mia",
    age: 10,
    heightInInches: 52
  },
  {
    name: "Jaya",
    age: 9,
    heightInInches: 45
  },
  {
    name: "Kiana",
    age: 10,
    heightInInches: 55
  },
  {
    name: "Alex",
    age: 11,
    heightInInches: 48
  }
];
console.log(tallEnoughToRide(groupA));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the combination of filter() and map():

```
console.log(groupA.filter(obj => obj.heightInInches >= 48).map(obj => obj.name));
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer, yes there actually is. Compute wise they are very similar.
But the readability is much better. In one line it's very clear what it should do.

```
let tallEnoughToRide = groupA.filter(e => e.heightInInches >= 48)
```

Extracting the names only looks like:

```
let tallEnoughToRide = groupA.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if(curr.heightInInches >= 48)
        acc.push(curr.name)
    return acc;
}, []);
```

The readability of the `reduce` function isn't actually very good.
Again, performance is very similar because it's still **O(n)**

It's up to you what to use. What you prefer. Long and explaining code or shorthanded code.

I saw this line or similar, like the following in this thread very often:

```
let result = groupA.filter(p => p.heightInInches >= 48).map(p => p.name)
```

**Don't** actually use this if you care about performance, which you should if you didn't already. Because you are giving up on compute performance to **O(2n)**. You are also using more memory since you create one extra array.